# How can I style a span tag within a h2 tag in Css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a simple website But it's not showing exactly what I want
In my HTML I did not assign the span to any class or id. How can I do that?

The h2 tag looks like this:

```html
<h2> Falafel <span>New</span></h2>
```

How can I Style it with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you can select it by selectinging the `h2` element and then simply using the child of the selector (space between the selectors):

```css
h2 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2> Falafel <span>New</span></h2>
```